# Maven Archive cannot be read or is not a valid Zip file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

When running the Maven Install in Eclipse for my XXXXClient (web service) project, I repeatedly got this message: 
"
**Archive for required library: 'X:/XXXX/XXXX/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0-SP4-redhat-4/cdi-api-1.0-SP4-redhat-4.jar' in project 'XXXXClient' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  XXXXClient      Build path  Build Path Problem**
"
for the following jars (dependencies in my project):

- jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- cdi-api-1.0-SP4-redhat-4.jar
- jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar
- jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.0.6.Final-redhat-1.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.3.redhat-1.jar
- jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar
- jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
- picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP8-redhat-1.jar
- jboss-as-controller-client-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA-redhat-1.jar
- resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar
- async-http-servlet-3.0-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar
- resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar
- resteasy-multipart-provider-2.3.8.Final-redhat-3.jar

Most of these jars can be found on the Maven Redhat repository: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/groups/product-techpreview/

In my Maven settings.xml, I have redhat-techpreview-all-repository and redhat-techpreview-eap-repository has active profiles.
Both profiles are configured: 
        `<releases>`
            `<enabled>true</enabled>`
            `<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>`
          `</releases>`
          `<snapshots>`
            `<enabled>false</enabled>`
            `<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>`
          `</snapshots>`

I noticed:

- All the jars mentionned above had a size of 57K and
- threw errors when running the following command: jar -tvf [jarfile.jar]. 
  I have also tried: mvn clean install -U (to force the redownload of jars), but it has not changed anything.

The only way I found to resolve my problem was to manually download each jar and replace them one by one.

Why did I have corrupted jar files in the first place and 
Was there a better way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you fixed the problem but got rid of the evidence (the wonky jars) so it's going to be very hard to say what was wrong.

Comment: Hi, actually I renamed every jar with the extension .jar.old. I will opened the old and new and compare them. 1+ for giving me the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the "-U" flag will force a download of missing JARs, but it's possible for a corrupted version to be added to the repository (such as network glitches during download), which the -U flag will not fix.
When I've had this problem before I've been able to fix it by deleting the local .m2 repository and allowing Maven to redownload them.

Comment: Hi, that's what I thought it may have been a network glitch. There is no way of knowing how many files could have been affected? As a last resort, I may always delete my local .m2. Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to check the files in the repository as a whole. If you want to get an idea of how many files are affected, you could try deleting the files one by one?
The .m2 repository is intended to work as a cache though, so it's supposed to be no problem to wipe it.

Comment: Worked for me removing the whole .m2 repository. (Not worked if only deleting the problematic package)